# Props Callback Function vs Emit in Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Working on building out a component library in vue.js and came across a question from an employee regarding callback function in props vs using emit. Didn't really have a good answer.

Is there any difference between the two?

```js
const EmitExample = defineComponent({
    emits: {
        change(input: string) {

        }
    },
    setup(_, { emit }) {
        return () => {
            return h('input', {
                onInput(event: {
                    target: HTMLInputElement
                }) {
                    emit('change', event.target.value)
                }
            })
        }
    }
})

const CallbackExample = defineComponent({
    props: {
        onChange: Function as PropType<(input: string) => void>
    },
    setup(props, { }) {
        return () => {
            return h('input', {
                onInput(event: {
                    target: HTMLInputElement
                }) {
                    if (props.onChange) {
                        props.onChange(event.target.value)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```